# c++ export an array of struct

Tags: c++11, struct

Hello i'v the following function that exports a single instance of a struct :

```
struct UserIdentity
{
std::string name;
int id;
};

std::map<std::string, int> g_UserIdentities = { { "Bob", 100 }, { "Jone", 101 },
            { "Alice", 102 }, { "Doe", 103 } };

/*
* Will be used in a DLL that will export UserIdentity struct
* OUT _UserIdentity
*/

void Ui_export(UserIdentity *_UserIdentity)
{
for (auto& t : g_UserIdentities)
    {
     _UserIdentity->name = t.first;
     _UserIdentity->id   = t.second;
    }

}
```

So please how could i export an array of _UserIdentity instead of a single instance in my function

```
void Ui_export(UserIdentity *_UserIdentity)
```

thank you .

Comment: make `Ui_export` take a `std::vector` by reference?

Comment: @Fureeish, i prefer to use  `_UserIdentity`

Comment: "I want to do `X`" - "*then use `Y` to achieve the functionality of `X`*" - "I don't want to use `Y`". Well, too bad. You could, from the caller's side, treat the `UserIdentity*` as a pointer to an array, but that's not recommended